# Getting Custom Image Attribute in Frontend

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

I've followed a tutorial found here: https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-image-attribute-category-magento-2/

With a slight modification which can be found in the InstallData, where I specified 'visible_on_front' :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $_eavSetupFactory;
    protected $_categorySetupFactory;


    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $setup = $this->_categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $setup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'grid_image', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Grid Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 9,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Content',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

However, I am unable to access the actual attribute in the frontend.  I'm grabbing the current category via the Registry, and find that the attribute simply isn't attached (tried checking using `$category->debug()`).  Any ideas for how I can get access to it on the frontend?

Comment: Do you need an image on the catalog?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code in your **PHTML** File.And get them your grid_image in frontend.

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$categoriesid = ['your category id'];
$imghelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
 ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
        <?php $homeimg = $category->getGridImage();
        if ($homeimg) : ?>
            <div class="box-inner">
                    <div class="homepage-category-img">
                        <div class="category-image-extra">
                            <img src="<?php echo $imghelper->resize($homeimg,420) ?>" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```